# Is there a way to detect when a specific process is flashing its window/taskbar icon?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Can I detect/listen for a process or program triggers a flash on its window? I.e. the orange flash on its taskbar icon. I have only found solutions that can trigger flash of the current application, not when another application/process does it.

Comment: SetWindowsHookEx() to register a shell hook, HSHELL_FLASH (0x8006) in the callback.  C# is not the ideal language to do this.

Comment: I would recommend using another language, you'll just make it harder for yourself if you were to use C#.